# PHP: add one item to a multidimensional array - alphabetically

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

**The situation**

Let's say I have a multidimensional array of people.

```
$people = array(
    '0' => array(
        'lastName' => 'Albertson',
        'firstName' => 'Bob',
        'phone' => '123-456-7890',
    ),
    '1' => array(
        'lastName' => 'Smith',
        'firstName' => 'Jenny',
        'phone' => '987-654-3210',
    ),
);
```

I want to add another person to this array, but I need the array to stay alphabetical by last name (and then first name, if two last names match).

Adding a person ends up putting them at the end of the array, so if I do a for loop, this person appears at the end instead of in the middle where I want him:

```
$people[] = array(
    'lastName' => 'McAlester',
    'firstName' => 'Jim',
    'phone' => '123-123-1234',
);
```

**What I've tried**

I have tried the array_msort function found on the [php.net multisort page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) - like so:

```
$people = array_msort($people, array('lastName'=>SORT_ASC, 'firstName'=>SORT_ASC));
function array_msort($array, $cols) {
    $colarr = array();
    foreach ($cols as $col => $order) {
        $colarr[$col] = array();
        foreach ($array as $k => $row) { $colarr[$col]['_'.$k] = strtolower($row[$col]); }
    }
    $eval = 'array_multisort(';
    foreach ($cols as $col => $order) {
        $eval .= '$colarr[\''.$col.'\'],'.$order.',';
    }
    $eval = substr($eval,0,-1).');';
    eval($eval);
    $ret = array();
    foreach ($colarr as $col => $arr) {
        foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
            $k = substr($k,1);
            if (!isset($ret[$k])) $ret[$k] = $array[$k];
            $ret[$k][$col] = $array[$k][$col];
        }
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

This does put the array in alphabetical order. But...

**The problem**

The array_msort function preserves numeric keys. So, I end up with (using print_r)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [lastName] => Albertson
            [firstName] => Bob
            [phone] => 123-456-7890
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [lastName] => McAlester
            [firstName] => Jim
            [phone] => 123-123-1234
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [lastName] => Smith
            [firstName] => Jenny
            [phone] => 987-654-3210
        )

)
```

When I loop through the array to output, because the added person has an index of 2, it is output last - alphabetical order is not preserved.

This is a simplified example - in reality I have a couple hundred people in the array, and they vary from time to time, so the exact number of the key I need to add changes. I need a way to add a person alphabetically by last name, then by first name, and somehow have the numeric indexes updated so they are in order too.

Comment: Do and `return array_values($ret);` to ge an fresh index from 0-x

Comment: Question: You talking about _couple hundred people in the array_ why are you not using a database?? There sorting and other stuff is more easy than with php. `ORDER BY lastname ASC, name DESC`

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions The initial array does come from a database. Problem is I am manually adding a person, who cannot be added to the database, into the array.

Comment: And from where comes the _manually_ added data?  Do you have to always do this, because you will not add the user to the database? But i try a simple soution, wait make an answer.

Comment: While this is a detailed and well written question, this question *topic* has been raised before.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions: your first comment worked perfectly. If you want to add it as an answer I'd be happy to accept it. The problem is the hundreds come from an HR database. The manually added "person" is a mascot, who cannot be added to HR database because it would cause payroll problems and all sorts of headaches. They don't have a way to include non-employees. I appreciate all the suggestions - I did search for quite awhile but only found solutions like array_splice where you must know the exact numeric index to add where you want.

Comment: Made an answer.

Comment: @Martin thank you. I hadn't seen that but it is definitely the same situation.

Comment: Make your life easier: use the name as the index, instead of the integers. Then sorting is easy.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins that's pretty much what JustOnUnderMillion does in their answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Quick Fix**

Do and `return array_values($ret);` in `array_msort` to get an fresh index from 0-n

OR

**Keep it Simple** Solution

```
$test = array(
         array('a'=>'abc','b'=>'abc'),
         array('a'=>'abd','b'=>'abc'),
         array('a'=>'abc','b'=>'abd'),
    );

$new = array();
foreach($test as $set){
    $ref = str_pad($set['a'],20,'Z').str_pad($set['b'],20,'Z');
    $new[$ref]=$set;
}
ksort($new);
print_r(array_values($new));
```

What happens here

- we iterate over all entries from `$test`
- then we make an sortable refer from the 2 fields and use it as key
- after we collect all, we sort the array by key

**Result**

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [a] => abc
        [b] => abc
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [a] => abc
        [b] => abd
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [a] => abd
        [b] => abc
    )
)
```

This solution ignores dublicates, mean all `a` & `b` combinations must be unique. (Means: hopefully you have only one `Jim McAlester` in your datasets)

Comment: Sadly there is one case where two people have the same first and last name. But `array_values` solves the problem without having to rethink the whole solution. For those in the future looking: also see Martin's comment on this question - it links to another solution that may be less memory intensive.

Comment: @WebElaine Take what fits your needs :-) And to _memory intensive_ your `array_msort` uses strings and `eval()` creates 2 new arrays and so on... ;-)  Have a nice dev-day

Comment: I'm afraid there are quite a few problems with this code; @JustOnUnderMillions. : 1) repetition names are removed, as human names *are* a small dataset, there ***will*** be repetitions, your code deletes them (fails to return them). 2) Your sorting algorithm only seems to sort in ASC order rather than DESC order. 3) You're not clearing up after your `foreach`.

Comment: @Martin 1) stated in the answer see `dublicates`. 2) SimpleSolution is not for everthing, but `ksort` is not the only option. 3) garbage_collector and please come on little petty.

Comment: I run your code and it does not return duplicate names, so two `Jim McAlester` values return only one array row. That's pretty crucial to a dataset of human names. Yes, foreach is a little on a minor side, but it's worth doing these things properly `:-)`!

Comment: *(just FYI the down vote is not me, I'm holding off hoping you're busy editing the post!!)*

Comment: @Martin I **sayed** in the answer, that this solution ignores dublicates. Dont typ before you dont have read something to the end. have a day!

Comment: So what is the OP meant to do with a sorted array of 300 rows and an *unsorted* array of 10+ other names which have been removed due to duplication? This seems like it would leave them in a worse data-state than they started in...

Comment: There are 2 solutions here. The first works fine. And yes, JustOnUnderMillions, the memory intensive part is not just your code but also the msort - both of those snippets are replaced now with the duplicate question's answer. I still appreciate your time explaining a couple options and am upvoting. People sure are wanting to nitpick today.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `usort`. It's simple and doesn't preserve keys.

```
usort($people, function($p1, $p2){
    return strcmp("$p1[lastName] $p1[firstName]", "$p2[lastName] $p2[firstName]");
});
```

Comment: It should also be worth noting this works also with duplicate name values. This should be the correct answer.

Comment: Agreed, this is a better solution. I did change `strcmp` to `strnatcasecmp` as in the duplicate question's answer but found the version here to be shorter and more elegant, as it keeps the function right with the call.

Comment: I agree that a case-insensitive comparison function is better for this.

Answer (score 1):

First, don't use eval. Ever.

Second, don't think of this as a multidimensional array. It technically is, but conceptually it's just a list of persons. Each person happens to be represented by an array, but that is irrelevant to the problem.

PHP offers [usort](http://php.net/manual/function.usort.php), which allows you to define your own comparison function. To sort by last name first, then by first name:

```
usort($people, function ($a, $b) {
    $x = strcmp($a['lastName'], $b['lastName']);                                                                                                   
    if ($x !== 0) {                                                                                                                                
        return $x;                                                                                                                                 
    }                                                                                                                                              

    return strcmp($a['firstName'], $b['firstName']);                                                                                               
});
```

Comment: plus one for `Don't use eval`. An important point.

Answer (score -1):

Simple function to sort an array by a specific key. Maintains index association. [source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php)

```
<?php

function array_sort($array, $on, $order=SORT_ASC)
{
    $new_array = array();
    $sortable_array = array();

    if (count($array) > 0) {
        foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
            if (is_array($v)) {
                foreach ($v as $k2 => $v2) {
                    if ($k2 == $on) {
                        $sortable_array[$k] = $v2;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $sortable_array[$k] = $v;
            }
        }

        switch ($order) {
            case SORT_ASC:
                asort($sortable_array);
            break;
            case SORT_DESC:
                arsort($sortable_array);
            break;
        }

        foreach ($sortable_array as $k => $v) {
            $new_array[$k] = $array[$k];
        }
    }

    return $new_array;
}

$people = array(
    12345 => array(
        'id' => 12345,
        'first_name' => 'Joe',
        'surname' => 'Bloggs',
        'age' => 23,
        'sex' => 'm'
    ),
    12346 => array(
        'id' => 12346,
        'first_name' => 'Adam',
        'surname' => 'Smith',
        'age' => 18,
        'sex' => 'm'
    ),
    12347 => array(
        'id' => 12347,
        'first_name' => 'Amy',
        'surname' => 'Jones',
        'age' => 21,
        'sex' => 'f'
    )
);

print_r(array_sort($people, 'age', SORT_DESC)); // Sort by oldest first
print_r(array_sort($people, 'surname', SORT_ASC)); // Sort by surname

/*
Array
(
    [12345] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12345
            [first_name] => Joe
            [surname] => Bloggs
            [age] => 23
            [sex] => m
        )

    [12347] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12347
            [first_name] => Amy
            [surname] => Jones
            [age] => 21
            [sex] => f
        )

    [12346] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12346
            [first_name] => Adam
            [surname] => Smith
            [age] => 18
            [sex] => m
        )

)
Array
(
    [12345] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12345
            [first_name] => Joe
            [surname] => Bloggs
            [age] => 23
            [sex] => m
        )

    [12347] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12347
            [first_name] => Amy
            [surname] => Jones
            [age] => 21
            [sex] => f
        )

    [12346] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12346
            [first_name] => Adam
            [surname] => Smith
            [age] => 18
            [sex] => m
        )

)
*/

?>
```

Comment: Close, but I need to sort on 2 values: first sort by last name, then if any last names are equal, sort by first name.